# Segmentation fault when scrolling in Elasticsearch using Python API

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch Python API to calculate some stuff based on the data I stored in my ES cluster. For my calculation I need to call all documents which satisfy certain conditions and get certain information from them. Therefore I am doing a scroll with a size of 1000 and a duration of 1 second. I have written a Python script which uses ES-Python to do the job for me.

However, always after a little more than 1400 scrolls the script quits with the error "`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`". I have tried to increase the scroll size to 10000 instead but still the same problem happens. Following is the part of the script where I'm doing the scrolling:

```
page = Elasticsearch().search(index = my_index, scroll = "1s", size = 1000, body = { "_source" : [ "_id", "@timestamp", my_field], "query" : {"bool":{"must" : [{"exists":{ "field" : my_field }},{"exists":{ "field" : "@timestamp" }}]}}})
sid = page['_scroll_id']
scroll_size = page['hits']['total']
while (scroll_size > 0):
    print "Scrolling..."
    # Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll
    scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])
    print "scroll size: " + str(scroll_size)
    page = Elasticsearch().scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '1s')
    # Update the scroll ID
    sid = page['_scroll_id']
```

I could find out that the line `page = Elasticsearch().scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '1s')` is responsible for the error. I have checked the scroll id and it is always the same (at least until the error is thrown).
Has anybody faced a similar problem or does anybody know how this can be solved?

I am running both Python and Elasticsearch on the same server with OS Ubuntu 14.04. Python version is 2.7.6 and ES version is 5.0.0

Comment: Have you considered using the scan helper instead? (http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.scan)

Comment: I didn't know about it before. Is there any working example on using the scan helper? I have been trying with it but could not figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

(posting this as an answer because code formatting doesn't work in comments)

Try something like this:

```
import elasticsearch
import elasticsearch.helpers

scanner = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(client=elasticsearch.Elasticsearch), index=my_index, query={...}, scroll='1s')
for doc in scanner:
    #Do something
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! At the end it didn't have to do with the scan API but rather with the operations I was doing inside my loop since I was saving the data I retrieve from ES in arrays which are extended with each iteration so at some point the memory was exhausted

Answer (score 0):

At the end I figured out it had nothing to do with scrolling in ES but it was a memory problem. Inside the loop I was saving the output coming from ES into arrays which were extended in each iteration. So at some point the memory limit was reached.